# C free an instance, which is pointed by other pointers

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have the following C code. I have two pointers pointing to the same object.
It says double free error. Can someone help to see what the problem is? Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct edge {
    int head;
} edge_t;

typedef struct edge_list_t {
    edge_t *edge;
} edge_list_t;
int main() {
    edge_list_t *p1;
    edge_list_t *p2;
    edge_t *c;

    p1 = malloc(sizeof(edge_list_t));
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(edge_list_t));

    c = malloc(sizeof(edge_t));

    p1->edge = c;
    p2->edge = c;

    free(c);

    if (p2->edge) {
        printf("not freed\n");
        free(p2->edge);
    } else {c
        printf("freed\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `free`ing a block of memory doesn't set the pointers that pointed to that block to NULL.

Comment: You allocate three blocks and you free one of them twice. That's not good.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  The `c` in `} else {c` is an unwanted interloper.  Note that a `main()` program conventionally returns 0 on success and 1 (or any non-zero value) to indicate some sort of failure.  But otherwise you've created a succinct question — well done.

Comment: @OP: maybe you want to look at the concept of [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), is that something you're after?

Answer (score 1):

```
p2->edge = c;

free(c);

if (p2->edge) {
    printf("not freed\n");
    free(p2->edge);
```

^ the last `free` is a double `free`. Remember that after the first `free` call, the value of `c` is an invalid value.

Comment: Could you tell me how to set the if condition such that the second free can be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: `if (p2->edge != c) free (p2->edge);`

Comment: @user2529913 `p2->edge = NULL;` after `free(c);`.

Comment: @ouah: That's a bad practice. You wind up having to make sure you NULL every possible pointer that might point to a block in order to free it, which just makes things more difficult. If you know which pointers that is, just don't use them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz he should use a pointer to a pointer to avoid this situation.

Comment: @ouah: One possible solution is to use a pointer to an intermediary structure. That intermediary structure can include a reference counter. If you drop the reference count to zero, you free both the intermediary structure and the underlying structure. In some cases, you can just put a reference counter in the underlying structure and don't call `free` unless you drop it to zero.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz after `free(c)`, `c` value is an invalid address and so the expression `p2->edge != c` is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: I think the problem is three-fold (or, one way of looking at the question shows three problems): (1) the code should not execute `free(c);` once it has transferred control of `c` to one of the structures; and (2) the code should not let `p1` and `p2` share `c`, and (3) the code should release `p1` and `p2` via a function which releases the `p->edge` element as well as the main structure.

Comment: @ouah "technically undefined behavior" -- Do you think that `*p1 = *p2` would be undefined?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In C an invalid pointer is a pointer that is neither a pointer to an object, nor a pointer to a function, nor a null pointer. So after `free` the value of the pointer is an invalid address.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `(C99, 6.9.5p6)` specifies the result of equality of null pointers, pointers to object and pointers to function but not of invalid pointers. Moreover in C99 Rationale it is written: *Regardless how an invalid pointer is created, any use of it yields undefined behavior. Even assignment, comparison with a null pointer constant, or comparison with itself, might on some systems result in an exception.*

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
p2->edge = c;

free(c);
```

when you free `c` the value of `c` does not change and even if it did the value of `p2->edge` would stay the same. It would hold the original value of c of course.
So you always free both `c` and `p2->edge` which both hold the same value.

To avoid that set `c` to NULL if you called `free()` on it and later check `if(c)` ,which will return false and not free `c` again.

Note: free() does not change the pointer in any way. It trust you that the pointer points to correct memory that was before never free()d.

Comment: I added free(p2->edge), the if condition still enters the second free path.
free(c);
  free(p2->edge);

  if (p2->edge) {
    printf("not freed\n");
    free(p2->edge);
  } else {
    printf("freed\n");
  }

Comment: C doesn't protect you from shooting yourself in the foot; it assumes that you know that you are aiming dangerous weapons and you have some cogent reason to put holes in the extremities of your anatomy.  It means it does not coddle beginners, which can be trying while you're learning the language.

Comment: When you do `free(p2->edge)`, that releases the memory pointed to by `p2->edge`. Now `p2->edge` points to memory that you have freed, so why do you free it again? `if (p2->edge)` is just the same as `if (p2->edge != NULL)`. `p2->edge` is not NULL, it points to the memory you freed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't free `c` once you've transferred control of it to `p1`, and you should not have both `p1` and `p2` sharing a single edge pointer, and you should release `p1` and `p2` via a function that also releases the edge pointer.  These observations lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct edge
{
    int head;
} edge_t;

typedef struct edge_list_t
{
    edge_t *edge;
} edge_list_t;

// Will acquire a loop when you have an actual list of edges
static void free_edge_list(edge_list_t *e)
{
    free(e->edge);
    free(e);
}

int main(void)
{
    edge_list_t *p1;
    edge_list_t *p2;
    edge_t *c;

    p1 = malloc(sizeof(edge_list_t));
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(edge_list_t));

    c = malloc(sizeof(edge_t));

    p1->edge = c;

    c = malloc(sizeof(edge_t));
    p2->edge = c;

    free_edge_list(p1);
    free_edge_list(p2);

    return 0;
}
```

In general, you should check that memory allocations succeed; this code (still) doesn't do that.